# How to add/mount block storage on DigitalOcean droplet under server root /

Tags: linux, mount, storage, vps, digital-ocean

I have created new CentOS x64 droplet on Digital Ocean and while doing that I have added block storage of 100GB as a additional storage.

But when i logged in to my VPS I see it like this :

```
[root@centos-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        25G  940M   25G   4% /
devtmpfs        474M     0  474M   0% /dev
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           496M   13M  484M   3% /run
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda        100G   61M   95G   1% /mnt/volume_nyc3_01
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/0
```

As you can see the additional storage volume is added as separate mount point as:

```
/dev/sda        100G   61M   95G   1% /mnt/volume_nyc3_01
```

How can I make this block storage usable under, let’s say, something like this:

```
/usr/share/nginx/
```

So basically my VPS has 25GB storage under root `/`
and 100GB storage mounted under `/mnt/volume_nyc3_01`

What I want is, total 125GB storage accessible under root `/` 
how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but from the `df` command output, the volume is already mounted.

Maybe you can create a symlink to the path you want to access that volume from.. say

```
ln -s /mnt/volume_nyc3_01 /usr/share/nginx
```

Comment: i want to use 100GB additional storage and 25GB storage space on root / to be 125GB so i can use all of it on the same path /usr/share/nginx

Comment: That won’t work without LVM or the like. You can use 100 GB. And then, in the other partition you can use 25 GB.

Answer (score 1):

> So basically my VPS has 25GB storage under root `/` and 100GB storage
>   mounted under `/mnt/volume_nyc3_01`
>
> What I want is, total 125GB storage accessible under root `/`  how can
>   I do that?

You can’t do what you are describing. When you add block storage to a VPS like that, it’s as if you are adding an external hard drive to your system and it is mounted under a separate volume.

Your two choices are seeing if you can increase your root volumes size using Digital Ocean’s tools. This will most likely require downtime and a rebuilding of the root volume.

But that said, that is not a very good long term strategy. The way many people use Linux/Unix servers like that is to have a root volume that can boot up and store the core applications you need and then use an additional volume to store data and such. Typically these volumes are mounted under `/opt/` and then your application uses that.

The benefit of using volumes like that is you never really have to worry about your increasing of storage needs negatively affecting your root system.

Comment: so i need to use alias to tell nginx to use mounted path like /opt/ ?